Electrolux dishwasher error: i10 (water supply issue)
I got an "i10" error code on my Electrolux dishwasher, at least I think it supposed to be an "i" (see attached pictures) . According to the manual it is some water supply issue. However I see the water flowing. I thought it may be some kind of blockage inside. I opened the left side of the dishwasher. I cleaned all what I could, but I still got the same error code. The program starts, the water starts to flow in, 2 minutes later it shows the error code and umps out the water. I tried several times, it always does the same. First time I try to repair a dishwasher, I am not even sure what I supposed to see. I could not find a service manual, so I am not sure where are the sensors, how many they are and what signal they should emit...
And just curiosity: what is that cylinder  pinkish thing on the side of the box
The exact name of the dishwasher is: Electrolux ga60lisw




tried everything from support?

yes. The water-flow looks normal to me, however never checked the dishwasher inside before, so I don't know how it would look otherwise. Anyway, I checked the hoses and other places for something blocking the flow, couldn't find anything. I also don't experience any change in the water pressure in the flat.

What are those things that look like beans in the tank?  Could a filter or screen be blocked by them?

I also wondered that. They are not moving, looks like a big firm pinkish gel. I couldn't open that tank, may be glued together.

Can you backflush it?

What would that mean?
